# Solving a first-order transport PDE with initial/boundary conditions on a halfline

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, initial-value-problems

I have another question that I need help with.

My main issue concerns the following problem (to which I came up with a general solution for - see below...further, the question is given exactly how it is presented):

***Problem:***

Solve the initial-boundary value problem:

$\begin{cases}u_{t}+3u_{x}+2u=0,~~~t,x\in\mathbb{R}^{+}\\
~\\
u(0,x)=\sin(x),~~u(t,0)=t.\end{cases}$

The general solutions I came up with is $u(t,x)=e^{-\frac{1}{5}(t+3x)}F(3t-x)$, where $F\in C^{1}(\mathbb{R})$. This can be derived in a number of ways, but the way I did it is via the following change of variables, $\xi=t+3x,~\eta=3t-x$. Details are omitted, however, using the change-of-variables previously mentioned will provide the transformed PDE of $u_{\xi}+\frac{1}{5}u=0$ which can be easily solved with the integrating factor $I=e^{\frac{1}{5}\int d\xi}=e^{\frac{1}{5}\xi}$, and then partially integrating the equation after multiplying both sides by $I$...this gives the general solution I provided above. Furthermore, using the initial condition $u(0,x)=\sin(x)$ will give a unique solution of $u(t,x)=-e^{-2t}\sin(3t-x)$ - note that the terms invovling the variable $x$ in the exponent of $e$ will cancel after applying this initial condition.

This is where I need help, as applying the second, boundary condition of $u(t,0)=t$ will yield $t=-e^{-2t}\sin(3t)$. I've also tried using this condition, $u(t,0)=t$, with the general solution *first* to come up with its, respective, unique solution (because we get a different $F$), but then I run into the same problem when trying to use the remaining boundary condition.

I mainly just need a hint on how the remaining mechanics work.

Comment: Sorry that I forgot the first few words of the problem-statement upfront. I just edited it, and it is exact as of now.

Comment: @Winther I used Mathematica to confirm what you said...it provided an imaginary answer.  I asked my Professor about it, and he recommended to used the characteristic method, and then look at the geometry of things to develop the solution.  I have yet to return the this problem, but I at least know my solution is correct.

Comment: @Winter (Sorry for not mentioning this) The problem is from a take-home midterm that we turned in last week, and I know I couldn't provide the full answer.  I unfortunately don't have a link for the problem, as I have a hard copy of it, but the problem is exact.

Comment: I think I was wrong. You need to define a different function $F(z)$ for $z<0$ and $z>0$ and then you get the correct solution I think. However the drawback is that $F$ will not be $C^1$ at $z=0$.

Comment: @Winter I will try both suggestions:  Solving via the characteristic method and what you suggest at the same time - also, sorry for my typo in my second comment above - I meant to say that my general solution is correct, and I didn't mean to impose that I have established the overall (unique) solution

Comment: For reference I find $u(t,x) = e^{-2t} F(x-3t)$ where $F(z) = \left\{\matrix{\sin(z) & z\geq 0\\ -\frac{z}{3}e^{-\frac{2z}{3}} & z \leq 0}\right.$.

Comment: @Winther Thank you for your unique solution.  I have to work (actually prove) the last problem of the assignment, and then I'm coming back to this immediately.  That being said, I'll be total finished with everything after that, and it was no smooth ride during which, that's for sure!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can try to deal with this using a special reflection from half-line to the entire line, but I prefer a direct approach. The characteristics are lines $t=t_0+s$, $x=x_0+3s$, with parameter $s$. Along any such line we have $du/ds = -2u$, and solving this ODE yields $$u(t_0+s,x_0+3s)=e^{-2s}u(t_0,x_0)$$
It remains to figure out what $(t_0,x_0)$ should be here. Think of going backward along a characteristic line: you hit either $t=0$ or $x=0$ 
Accordingly,   there are two cases:

1. If $x>3t$, then the initial point is $(0,x-3t)$, at which the initial value is $\sin(x-3t)$. Also, $s=t$ here, leading to $u(x,t)=e^{-2t}\sin(x-3t)$.
2. If $x<3t$, then the initial point is $(t-x/3,0)$, at which the initial value is $t-x/3$. Also, $s=x/3$ here, leading to $u(x,t)=e^{-2x/3}(t-x/3)$.

These give the same result on the boundary $3x=t$, which is nice, and is a reflection of the fact that $(\sin 3x)_{x=0} = (t)_{t=0}$. The solution is not differentiable on $x=3t$, which is not unusual for the transport equation: it carries forward whatever singularities and corners were present in the initial data. Here the data had a "corner" due to the combination of initial and boundary conditions.

Comment: Norman, tank you for your answer!  I was having trouble setting up the ODE in regards to the characteristic method (I, at least, had the right-hand side of the ODE correct...woo hoo).  We've covered in class what you mean about "re-tracing" the characteristic lines backwards.  I'm applying the finishing touches now, and thank you (again) for your solution...this helps A LOT!